# Search analytics data from Google Search Console differs when downloaded to Excel

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, google-search

I downloaded all of the search analytics data for my website for last 3 months. I moved 5000 records at a time and exported it as an MS-Excel file. I can see that the data in the online console and that of the file differs.

e.g. the count of clicks for certain pages differ by hundreds.
I can see clicks coming up as 0 where the actual value was 171.
I had the default report settings with the secondary parameter of Date.

PS- I was working on around 1,50,000 records.
Is this a known issue? Also is there any API that I can use to download search analytics data rather than manually downloading the Excel files.

Comment: is it .xls or is it .csv?

Comment: @JosipIvic The files are of .xlsx extension.